# How to reverse or create a group sprites pinned to other objects on a specific pattern.

Tags: construct-2

Hey guy i am creating a game, where i am facing some problem.

I am creating a sprite, SpriteT on runtime with a rope effect like snake with proper instances. Also am creating Text object pinned on the rope style sprites with instances and need to handle those sprites objects with text instances.

I gave the leadsprite 8 directions where other families are attached to leadsprite.

Now i want is when i rotate the leadsprite to 90 and then to 180 that is top left movement. I need is to compare the instances of equal positions of sprite Whenever i do this the system never compares each value of sprites. i don't know how to compare the elements of one single array that is definately instances to each other's position record and if they match i want to destroy the sprites objects.

this includes i think there must be some pattern now i need to reverse the remaining spriteT to the Leadsprite on the same pattern.. This is where i am lacking whenever i do this

```
  // On Destroyed
    OnObjectDestroyed() {
     // This contain let 10 number of sprite to attached with the center of one next sprite.
         SpriteTObjectFamily.setPositionTowardsObject(ImagePoint0);
    }
```

I have just started and a Noob. Please help this is actually doing in Construct2. Any help would be great. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the node as parent and inherit other nodes as child. Set position of child nodes as position.parentNode.x and position.parentNode.y which follows the position of your rootNode.